# Serving user-specific CSS customizations with Node.js

Tags: css, node.js, templates

I want to permit users of my Node.js application to customise some elements of their visual experience normally defined by a CSS (e.g. the color scheme).

One idea could be a fully dynamic approach on the server side with some sort of CSS-preprocessing or templating, that I could execute in a similar manner to Jade templates when processing user requests, e.g. along the lines of `res.render(html_template, css_template, vars)`. Is there anything suitable, will `less.js` work here for production use?

Another idea could be to transfer such customisation to the client side, persist it there and apply it with some custom-made javascript. Is there anything of this sort?

Answer (score 0):

you can use less or sass on server side, and generate precompile files for users using grant. on client side link additional css file.

Comment: less explicitly states that it is not recommended for production use. If you think it is, what is this opinion based on? I would prefer a lighweight dynamic approach rather than precompiling and serving everything statically, is there anything (apart from lack of caching) that speaks against that?

Comment: @OlegS. LESS is fine for production, just not the client-side (javascript-in-browser) version because of performance. Since this is server side tech (node) LESS will compile to plain old CSS before reaching a browser, so you're in the clear.

Comment: Ok, thanks both. So what would be the cleanest way to serve user-specific less-compiled css? Would it be by providing a node request handler for e.g. `/styles/overrides.css` that is dynamically compiled with less using user session information?